# Improving functions to backup and restore a bash dictionary

Tags: bash, dictionary, backup, restore

I wrote this two simple functions to backup and restore the content of a bash dictionary:

```
declare -A dikv
declare -A dict

backup_dikv()
{
    FILE=$1
    rm -f $FILE

    for k in "${!dikv[@]}"
    do  
        echo "$k,${dikv[$k]}" >> $FILE
    done
}

restore_dict()
{
    FILE=$1
    for i in $(cat $FILE)
    do  
        key=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d ",")
        val=$(echo $i | cut -f 2 -d ",")
        dict[$key]=$val
    done
}

# Initial values
dikv=( ["k1"]="v1" ["k2"]="v2" ["k3"]="v3" ["k4"]="v4")

backup_dikv /tmp/backup
restore_dict /tmp/backup

echo "${!dict[@]}"
echo "${dict[@]}"
```

My questions:

1. As you can see, these two funcions are very limited as the name of the backuped (dikv) and restored (dict) dictionaries is hardcoded. I would like to pass the dictionary as an input ($2) argument, but I don't know how to pass dictionaries as funcion arguments in bash.
2. Is this  method to write keys and values into a file, using a string format ("key","value") and parse that string format to restore the dictionary, the unique / most eficient way to do that? Do you know some better mechanism to backup and restore a dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't pass array to functions. You can pass the **name** of the array to a function and then use `${!name}` to access the array.

Comment: One possibilitiy would be to format the array in a way that it can be recreated later with `eval`. However, care must be taken for characters inside the keys or values which have special meaning to the shell, for instance single apostrophs. Perhaps the safest approach would be to write the key-value-pairs to a file by separating them by a NUL byte (the only safe separator I can think of), and recreating it from this representation.

Comment: `declare -p dikv` is *supposed* to print something that can be `eval`ed to recreate the array, but it doesn't always handle weird characters in the indexes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `declare -p` to reliably serialize variables regardless of their type

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f saved_vars.sh ]; then
  # Restore saved variables
  . saved_vars.sh
else
  # No saved variables, so lets populate them
  declare -A dikv=([foo]="foo bar from dikv" [bar]="bar baz from dikv")
  declare -A dict=([baz]="baz qux from dict" [qux]="qux corge from dict")
fi

# Serialise backup dikv dict into the saved_vars.sh file
declare -p dikv dict >'saved_vars.sh'

printf %s\\n "${!dict[@]}"
printf %s\\n "${dict[@]}"

printf %s\\n "${!dikv[@]}"
printf %s\\n "${dikv[@]}"
```

Comment: Not sure to understand this, I run your script and always generates a saved_vars.sh with this content:
declare -A dikv
declare -A dict

Comment: Are you sure to run bash and not some other shell?

Comment: $ bash --version
GNU bash, versión 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licencia GPLv3+: GPL de GNU versión 3 o posterior <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to pass arrays to functions, using local -n in this way:

```
declare -A dikv
declare -A dict

backup_dictionary()
{
    local -n dict_ref=$1
    FILE=/tmp/backup

    for k in "${!dict_ref[@]}"
    do  
        echo "$k,${dict_ref[$k]}" >> $FILE
    done
}

restore_dictionary()
{
    local -n dict_ref=$1
    FILE=/tmp/backup

    for i in $(cat $FILE)
    do  
        key=$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d ",")
        val=$(echo $i | cut -f 2 -d ",")
        dict_ref[$key]=$val
    done
}

dikv=( ["k1"]="v1" ["k2"]="v2" ["k3"]="v3" ["k4"]="v4")

backup_dictionary dikv
restore_dictionary dict

echo "${!dict[@]}"
echo "${dict[@]}"
```

Still trying to find the most convenient way to backup and restore the content.